# Cannot apply padding to <b>

Tags: css

Is there a reason why the padding-top is not working for the  tag? See http://jsfiddle.net/MMwdR/

```
<b>hello world</b>​

b {
    padding-top: 100px;
}
​
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

display it as a block.

```
display: block;
```

Answer (score -1):

To add on to what was said, update your CSS to:

```
b {
     display: block;
     padding-top: 100px;
}
```

Otherwise the element is displayed as a part of the line, so you cannot add `padding-top`, etc.